# Webpack 4 not importing Bootstrap mixins when working just with BS Grid

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, webpack-4

I'm using Webpack 4 and i'm trying to work with the bootstrap 4 sass grid, my approach is to decouple the bootstrap grid classes from my HTML so i'm tryin to import the grid mixins and the grid itself in order to use the bootstrap mixins inside my sass components but i for some reason im not being able to reach the bootstrap mixins when i import them from my node__modules folder:

This is the file (app.scss) where im importing all the files from node_modules:

```
 //----------------------------------*\
// BOOTSTRAP VARIABLES OVERRIDE
// AVOID BOOTSTRAP GRID TO BE GENERATED
//----------------------------------*/
$enable-grid-classes: false;

//----------------------------------*\
// BOOTSTRAP CORE
//----------------------------------*/
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";

//----------------------------------*\
// BOOTSTRAP GRID
//----------------------------------*/
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss";
```

And this is the grid.scss file where im trying to use the mixins from the bootstrap mixins.scss:

```
.grid-container {
  @include make-container();
  @include make-container-max-widths; 
}
```

I have an scripts.js thats importing both files (have in mind that .grid-container is being imported by styles.scss:

```
 //----------------------------------*\
// LIBRARIES COMPONENTS
//----------------------------------*/
import "../scss/app.scss";

//----------------------------------*\
// LAYOUT, THEME & COMPONENTS
//----------------------------------*/
import "../scss/style.scss";
```

This is the error im getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!./src/scss/style.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

      @include make-container();
              ^
          No mixin named make-container
          in C:\Users\jpi\Documents\Proyectos\IMI\imienxarxa\Documentos\frontend\src\scss\layout\_grid.scss (line 2, column 12)
```

It's like for Webpack im not importing those bootstrap mixins at any point but im importing all of them on a different file (app.scss).

**UPDATE:**

If I import _grid.scss from the app.scss (the file where im importing all the bootstrap mixins) it actually works, im really confused why it does not work the other way since everything is being included in a single css file at the end. Any help will be really appreciated.